# Height of a child is not changing, and child is not centering

Tags: html, css

I am creating a nav bar for my custom website I want the `<a>` and `<li>` tags to be the same height as the `<ul>`, but when i attempt to do this the size of both the a and li tags remain default. Attempting to center this aswell, with no dice. Below is what I have attempted, to no luck. I'm assuming i can just use the UL as the nav bar and do it that way, but i want more customization with the nav bar. Any help appreciated! Apologies if i messed anything up as this is my first post on here.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navBox {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(209, 10, 10);
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 8%;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

````html
<header>
  <div id="navBox">
    <img src="bj_image.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Assign `display: flex` for `ul` and the browser will align everything as needed.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navBox {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(209, 10, 10);
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 8%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="navBox">
    <img src="bj_image.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```